# ChatWithPdf plugin error when used, how to make it work

Tags: chatgpt-api

When I used the chatwithpdf plugin in the chatgpt4, it said 'Error communicating with plugin 'ChatWithPDF'', what's wrong with it?

I deleted it and downloaded it again, making no difference.Is it mistake of the plugin or other things?